widget get dispose when i click on modal input field
I have a parent stateful widget (second page of my main bottom navigation menu) which trigger the AddIngredientDialog modal with a button.
When I get focus on input field inside the modal, modal does not pop up and parent widget get dispose and go back to homepage.
I tried everything, to change modal but error persist. I also changed the Container that wrap the modal with Padding. Nothing.
I have this issue since I updated Flutter 3.24
  void showIngDialog() {
    showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      isScrollControlled: true,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AddIngredientDialog(
          onPressed: (ingredientData) {
            addIngredientData(ingredientData);
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: TextField(
              controller: _nameController,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Ingredient Name',
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: TextField(
              controller: _quantityController,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Quantity',
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 8.0),
            child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                final ing = IngredientList(
                  _nameController.text,
                  _quantityController.text,
                );
                widget.onPressed(ing);
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              child: const Text('Add'),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

I tried everything, to change modal but error persist. I also changed the Container that wrap the modal with Padding. Nothing.
